# Spring framework JpaRepository result

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to return different kind of results from a `JpaRepository`.

For example:

```
public interface ServiceRepository extends JpaRepository <Service, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT d FROM Staff p WHERE idService = :idservice")
    Collection<Staff> getStaffbyService(@Param("idservice") Long idservice);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by different kind of results ? Also, can you post `Service` class code?

Comment: you mean can a Service repository return a Staff object? Yes - look at count methods. You can also have native queries in the repository return custom objects

Comment: Yes it did work, i just needed to create the servicebean and the repository for the staff class too.